# Reconstruct "required field-of-view" equation with fixed distance to "required distance" equation with fixed FOV

Tags: geometry

I have the following formula:

```
fov = 2 * atan( height / ( 2 * dist ) ) * ( 180 / PI )
```

How would the same equation look like if you wanted to calculate `dist` (based on `fov` and `height`)? I.e.

```
dist = ...?
```

Source of question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out myself

```
dist = height / (2 * tan(PI * fov / 360))
```